# div CSS loading animation isn't showing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I have a page where were users click a button to submit a data to be processed the problem is this takes up to 30-40 secs so I want to prevent users to re-click the button again so I made a CSS loading animation in a div and call it in a js script tag but when I try running the js function it doesn't work i even tried running it in the console.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#q12').click(function() {
    $('#q11').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="loading" id="q11" style="display:none">
  <div class="obj"></div>
  <div class="obj"></div>
  <div class="obj"></div>
  <div class="obj"></div>
  <div class="obj"></div>
  <div class="obj"></div>
  <div class="obj"></div>
<div class="obj"></div>
</div>

<a href="{% url 'patients:analyse_images' image.pk %}"
  class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary"
  id="q12">Analyse</a>
```

Comment: Where is the element with id `q12`?

Comment: the link with button class

Comment: Change the anchor tag to button and add the redirection to on click method - check this sample - https://jsfiddle.net/hvpzw6mo/

Comment: but I can't call the link effectively as it's located under a form

Comment: @Ammarrady can you post the sample form which you are mentioning? and also I updated the jsfiddle with the form. I don't think it should make any difference.

Comment: what is written css in `loading` class? and is there any error in console ?

Comment: Wait, what is the intended behavior? You want them to click, to go some new route, then get served with a loading icon? You need to prevent the default behavior of the click on the a tag if that's the case (google the preventDefault() method on javascript events)

Comment: basically, when the users click the link the data of this object will be processed and they will be redirected to a url/page so before the redirection I want to show a loading screen as I said this takes some time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```js
document.querySelector('#q12').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // stop the click from triggering a route change
  e.preventDefault();
  // display the loader
  document.querySelector('#q11').style.display = 'block';
  // hide the "Analyse" element
  e.target.style.display = 'none';
})
```

```css
.obj {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading" id="q11" style="display:none">
  <div class="obj"></div>
  <div class="obj"></div>
  <div class="obj"></div>
</div>

<a href="{% url 'patients:analyse_images' image.pk %}"
  class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary"
  id="q12">Analyse</a>
```

If so, read up on the [preventDefault method of JavaScript events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

If you're fancy, you could use `setTimeout` to redirect users to some route after n seconds. You'd want to use that `setTimeout` function inside the `click` callback function above...

Comment: prevent default is to prevent the users from re-clicking the link ?

Comment: Ah no, sorry, in this case preventDefault is to prevent the default behavior of the event. With `<a>` tags, the default behavior of a click is that the user is navigated to the a tag's `href` attribute. We don't want them to go to a new route (we don't want the browser url to change), so we need to prevent that default behavior.

Comment: To clarify a little, the reason your function wasn't working was that the page changed once users clicked the a tag. You'll see that if you change the `href` attribute of the a tag in your code snippet to `https://google.com` and you click the a tag again--the page changes, which means your divs can't be displayed

Comment: it didn't work the button/link disappears and the data isn't submitted and even the loading div didn't show any idea?

Comment: yeah, I'm not very good with javascript..are you familiar with django?

Comment: I am but this sounds more like a freelance engagement than a stackoverflow question! Feel free to hit me up if you're really stuck: douglas . duhaime at gmail

Comment: ok, thanks for your help I was gonna ask about something I would change in the view but now I changed this anchor tag to a button and still the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with the link in the  tags in last line. Remove the href.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loading" id="q11" style="display:none">
          <div class="obj"></div>
          <div class="obj"></div>
          <div class="obj"></div>
          <div class="obj"></div>
          <div class="obj"></div>
          <div class="obj"></div>
          <div class="obj"></div>
          <div class="obj"></div>
    </div>

    <button id="q12">Analyse</button>
```

Comment: so how can I access/process the data?

Comment: Updated answer with the solution. Also, it is better to use button instead of links.

Comment: no, as I said in a comment it's located under a form.

Comment: thanks for your help but I can't take this approach. your help is really appreciated